# Has someone written (or is aware of) an instruction guide for setting up a RAMDisk and using it for pagefile.sys?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, ramdisk, pagefile

I was talking with a friend the other day about Windows in general and I mentioned that there is, unfortunately no way (that I was aware of) to disable the page file within Windows.  Regardless of the size of your RAM, there was always going to be pagefile.sys.

If you're like me, you don't want your memory paged on your HD if there really is no need for it.  He offered the brilliant suggestion I had never considered-- create a RAM Drive and set the page file to RAM Drive.

Of course, as he and I were both aware, I'm sure this has been done before.  I've never created a RAM Disk before?  Has anyone in the SU community ever done this and, if so, have a link to a good walkthrough on how to do this?

Comment: **Attention:** There is only a limited amount of memory given to drivers, called the [`non-paged` and `paged` pool](http://bit.ly/rttIee) memory sections. A page file is necessary for when the paged section gets full, as a gamer I have seen a game complain about paged pool memory just because I had my page file disabled on a 8 GB system. Conclusion: **Page files are necessary, they prevent paged pool depletion and actually [do speed up](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-throw-those-paging-files-away.html) your system.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily disable the page file. Jeff Atwood [blogged about disabling it](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/running-xp-with-the-pagefile-disabled.html) and the consequences. In any case, moving it to a RAMdisk is the worst thing you could do with it, since the page file is for storing stuff that already doesn't fit in memory. Reserving memory for a RAMDisk is going to only make *more* data get paged out, which will in turn require a larger paging file and RAMDisk, which will in turn leave less memory available, which will in turn page out more mem-- You can see where this is going.

Comment: [Disabling the paging file _by itself_ causes an increase in eviction pressure,](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dont-throw-those-paging-files-away.html) as read-write data pages push out untainted code pages.

Comment: Thanks for that blog post.  Although my current rig has more than enough RAM, Jeff's explanation does an excellent job of defining why a page file can be useful.

Answer (score 5):

Having a RAM disk for your pagefile defeats the whole purpose of having RAM in the first place.

The pagefile is used to page out memory pages to make room for other programs.  Setting a RAMdisk for the pagefile just uses RAM that the Memory manager could use, instead of paging them out. . .

It's like towing another car so you can use that second car to drive farther. . .

Comment: +1 for a good response, but bad analogy :P  It's more like you have $100 worth of gas, and can put it all in your first car, or half-half between the car you're towing.  You'll get further putting it all in one car, and it'll be a lot quicker then changing vehicles ;)  Oh, and @RLH - don't use a RAM disk for a pagefile.  'Nuff said.

Comment: I don't think people realize RAMdisks stopped being popular after we broke the 1MB barrier. . .

Answer (score 1):

There some tips on RAMDISK software on this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows

And some interesting discussion on whether the pagefile should be put on a RAMDISK or not: https://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows/34404#34404

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with a 32-bit windows client OS with a 3GB memory cap, you can use a ramdisk and physical address extension to make use of the invisible ram.  
the other posters are right that if your os allows you to address all the physical ram, putting pagefile.sys on a ramdisk is bass ackwards.  
however for certain programs that use the disk for scratch space it can still help...photoshop for example.